# Poco Mutex causes unhandled exception after close of the program

Tags: c++, mutex, poco-libraries

I get an unhandled exception if I close my program using Poco mutexes.

I use a global

```
 Poco::Mutex mymutex ;
```

in my cpp file, because I have a static class for logging (I also tried to declare it as a static member, but I got the same error).

The relevant part of my code (it's a static function):

```
void Log::log(std::string message)
{
    try
    {
        Poco::Mutex::ScopedLock lock(mymutex);

        std::ofstream f("log.txt", std::ios_base::app) ;
        f << message << std::endl ;
        f.close() ;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }
}
```

This part of the code works great in my program (there are no lines on each other like before using mutexes), but after I close my program, I get the following error message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x77c3a710 in myprogram.exe: 0xC0000005: 
Access violation writing location 0x00000014.
```

I also tried to use mymutex.lock() and mymutex.unlock() before and after writing to the file, but I got the same error.

And I also tried this code:

```
while(!mymutex.tryLock())
    Poco::Thread::sleep(30);
```

but it resulted an infinite loop, the program has not stopped after closing its window.

I use Visual Studio 2010 and Poco 1.4.

Comment: Sounds like you're accessing the mutex after it has been destroyed. Do you have another global object that is using your log function, possibly in its destructor?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, I had a global object, and it seems that its destructor ran after the mutex has been destroyed (and it's logging in its destructor too). I have restructured my program, and now it works! Thank you!